# iTextSharp table pushing another table to a new page

Tags: vb.net, itext

I have two tables on my PDF. The first one sometimes spans more than half the page, which forces the second to jump to a new page.

Here are my definitions:

```
        'Table Declaration
        Dim sglTblHdWidths(2) As Single
        sglTblHdWidths(0) = 200
        sglTblHdWidths(1) = 200
        sglTblHdWidths(2) = 102
        'Table ONE:
        Dim ToCCSub As New PdfPTable(sglTblHdWidths)
        ToCCSub.TotalWidth = 502.0F
        ToCCSub.LockedWidth = True
        'Table TWO:
        Dim tab As New PdfPTable(1)
        tab.TotalWidth = 502.0F
        tab.LockedWidth = True
```

And they're both added to the document afterward. How can prevent this from happening?

Comment: If the tables are too large for one page, what else should happen than the creation of a new page?

Comment: Is it OK for you if the table is split into two parts? If so, why don't you change the "set split late" property to `false`?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie Yes that worked! Thanks. You can answer below and I'll accept answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, iText won't split a row, but instead forward it to the next page.
You can change this default by changing the value of the `SplitLate` property:

```
tab.SplitLate = false;
```

Now the row in the table `tab` that was shown on the next page, will be split into two parts, so that the content is distributed over the current page and the next page.

Comment: For some reason this only worked when I added it to every single table on my PDF, tried only adding to the one I needed and I was still getting a split. Hopefully this helps someone else, trial and error helped me get this to work.